# Javascript how to set interval time to stop scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

This is the demo in jsfiddle, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ato0mf7u/1/)

What I want is let the scrolled items('one ', 'two', 'three', '4', '5', '6', '7') automatically scroll up like the demo showed, and stop 2 sec when it's in the middle position. But in my demo, it will shack for a while after stopping in the middle position.

Here is the place in my demo code for setting position.

```
if ((x == 0) || (x % 35== 0)) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        i.top = x + 'px';
    }, 1000);
} else {
    i.top = x + 'px';
}
```

Any one can help me? Thanks!

UPDATE:
The reason why I set 35 is because I found that the scrolled items are approximately in the middle position when it equals to 0, -35,-70,-105,.... But when I console all x, I found that the value of x is between (31, -251). Do you know how to find the exact position when each items are in the middle of position? Thanks!

Comment: that shakin looks very funny

Comment: Yes, funny. It seems it because of the conflict time between setTimeout and setInterval(which is in the bottom of my code)

Comment: +1 for the funny shake.

Comment: :( please help me figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: You should consider using more descriptive names for your variables.  I have no idea what's going on so I don't know how I can help you.

Comment: HI bobbyg603. You can easily understand it if you take a look at my code in jsfiddle. x is the  position which updated every 1 sec(based on the JS code in bottom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i modified your code a bit,

i set a variable "k" that the interval is assigned to and i clear the interval on stop and start it again after the timeout

looks good for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/ato0mf7u/3/
no funny shakin anymore ;-D

```
window.onload = addScrollers;


var i = 1;
var arr = ['one ', 'two', 'three', '4', '5', '6', '7'];
var mid;
var k;
function addScrollers() {

    var txt = arr[0];
    while (i < arr.length) {
        txt += '<p>' + arr[i] + '</p>';
        i++;
    }
    startScroll('myscroller', txt);

}

var speed = 10; // scroll speed (bigger = faster)
var dR = false; // reverse direction

var step = 1;
function objWidth(obj) {

    if (obj.offsetWidth) return obj.offsetWidth;
    if (obj.clip) return obj.clip.width;
    return 0;
}
function objHeight(obj) {

    if (obj.offsetHeight) return obj.offsetHeight;
    if (obj.clip) return obj.clip.height;
    return 0;
}
function scrF(i, sH, eH) {
    var x = parseInt(i.top) + (dR ? step : -step);
    if (dR && x > sH) {
        x = -eH;
    } else if (x < 1 - eH) {
        x = sH;
    }
    //when x is the times of 35, the positio is in middle
    if ((x == 0) || (x % 35== 0)) {
        clearInterval(k);
        setTimeout(function () {
            i.top = x + 'px';
            k = setInterval(function () {

             scrF(i, sH, eH);
             }, 1000 / speed);
        }, 1000);

    }
    else {
        i.top = x + 'px';
    }
    return x;
}
function startScroll(sN, txt) {


    var scr = document.getElementById(sN);
    var sW = objWidth(scr);
    var sH = objHeight(scr);
    scr.innerHTML = '<div id="' + sN + 'in" style="position:absolute; left:3px; width:' + sW + ';">' + txt + '<\/div>';
    var sTxt = document.getElementById(sN + 'in');
    var eH = objHeight(sTxt);

    mid = (eH - sH) / 2;

    sTxt.style.top = (dR ? -eH : sH) + 'px';
    sTxt.style.clip = 'rect(0,' + sW + 'px,' + eH + 'px,0)';


    k = setInterval(function () {

        scrF(sTxt.style, sH, eH);
    }, 1000 / speed);

}
```

Comment: Good that it works but why does resetting the interval inside the timeout correct it? It had me pretty confused

Comment: no, clearing the interval corrected it ! I just started it again to go on, effectively you dont need the interval at all, just call scrF() again after timeout

Comment: Well you'd need the interval other wise it would only move 1 position, wouldn't it? Still seems odd why clearing the interval would work. Atleast in my eyes

Comment: the interval in startScroll is only called 35 times, from then i clear it because otherwise it would still be running during the timeOut (that made the funny bounces), after timeout the interval in scrF gets started 35 times, clear and timeout and again and again and again. Important thing was that no interval runs during the timeout...this is why clearing it and start it again is the solution

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes perfect sense to me now! I didn't think that the interval would keep running during the timeout, how stupid of me.

Comment: Joan. Thanks for your kindly answer. The reason why I set 35 is because I found that the scrolled items are approximately in the middle position when it equals to 0, -35,-70,-105,.... But when I console all x, I found that the the value of x is between (31, -251). Do you know how to find the exact position when each items in the middle of position? Thanks!